# Node/JSON Issues

Tags: javascript, sql, json, node.js

So I am trying to figure out why my returned object every single time is just []? 
Here is my code:

```
var returnObject = [];

db.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;

for (var i in rows) 
{
  console.log('Data: ', rows[i]);

  var marker = 
  {
    o_ID:rows[i].o_ID,
    data:rows[i].data
  };

  returnObject[i]=marker;

  console.log(chalk.red(returnObject[i].o_ID));
  console.log(chalk.red(returnObject[i].data));

}
});

var sqsParams = {MessageBody: JSON.stringify(returnObject), QueueUrl :'---'};
```

For some reasons when I print the returnObject values they are correct but when it gets to the JSON.stringify something happens and sends to my SQS queue just [].

I thought maybe getting rid of the marker variable and just assigning

```
returnObject[i]=   {
    o_ID:rows[i].o_ID,
    data:rows[i].data
  };
```

But that still results in the same issue.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database queries in JavaScript are usually asynchronous. This means that the code inside your callback function `function(err, rows, fields)` will be run only *after* the database query has been done, whereas you assignment to `sqsParams` will be done right after the database query has been *started*. The result is that code inside your callback function has not been run before you `returnObject` with `JSON.stringify` and it is still in its original value `[]`.

Comment: ahhhh duhh.  I was wondering why.  Just popped that all in there db call and we are working perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your sqsParams variable is being set outside the db.query callback. As the db.query is asynchronous, your code is going to just fall through with an empty array.

Move your sqsParams variable into the callback you are supplying to db.query, eg:

```
        console.log(chalk.red(returnObject[i].o_ID));
        console.log(chalk.red(returnObject[i].data));
    }
    var sqsParams = {MessageBody: JSON.stringify(returnObject), QueueUrl :'---'};
    // Use sqsParams here
});
```